What are some ways I can get an LM5176 buck-boost converter to operate down to 2.5V input voltage without a separate power supply?
The datasheet for the LM5176 says it can primarily operate with an input voltage between 4.2V and 55V. However, the datasheet also says it can operate down to 2.5V input voltage, but only if the BIAS pin is powered by a higher voltage, like 8V.
For my project, the LM5176 will be powered by a wind turbine, so if winds are getting close to calm, the input voltage will likely drop below 4.2V; I want to take advantage of this opportunity and see if I can extract power out of the wind turbine all the way down to 2.5V
So, since the BIAS pin needs to be powered by a higher voltage during this condition, what are some ways I can power it?
Texas instruments sells plenty of super-low input voltage boost converters, but they also have very low maximum input voltage ratings; something like 10V or less. On a windy day, these boost controllers would likely be exposed to voltages produced by the turbine that are way too high (somewhere around 20V or 30V).
So far, my main idea is to "protect" the low-voltage boost converter with an LDO in front of its input pin. I think this would prevent it from being exposed to those higher voltages on a windy day.
My other idea is to ditch the use of a low-voltage boost converter, and just power the BIAS pin from the output of the buck-boost converter itself, which is 5V. The only problem with this is that the wind would have to spin the turbine so it makes more than 4.2V on startup in order for this to work.

Schematic is from Figure 8-1 in the Texas Instruments LM5176 Four-Switch Buck Boost Application Schematic found in the LM5176 datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm5176

Power Vbias from Vout when running. Switch a battery onto Vbias for 'booting it up' from off. As the battery will only be used for a short time when restarting, little capacity is needed. You could use a primary battery and replace it from time to time, or a rechargable.

Seeing that you have an AC supply use a voltage doubling (or trippling) rectifier to power this pin.
